# (Javascript with D3) Data from CSV file only being used once and returning undefined or NaN second time

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to use data to create a bubble chart [based on this code by Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) and have been trying to simplify it both so I can understand it better and so I can build upon it for my own purposes later.

At this time, it correctly displays all the bubbles with sizes based on the data, but it doesn't display the correct data in the circles, nor does it show that same data in the labels when hovering the mouse over the circles.

From what I can see it seems like the code changes the data when used the first time so I tried to get around it by reading from the file again, but while it seems to be getting the data from the file it just returns Animal entries as "undefined" and the numbers in "First" as NaN. What do I have to do to get the labels to display correctly?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg width="1200" height="500" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" text-anchor="middle"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var format = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(10);

d3.csv("animalcount.csv", function(d) {
    d.First = +d.First;
    if (d.First) return d;
    if (d.Animal) return d;
}, function(error, animal) {
  if (error) throw error;

    var root = d3.hierarchy({ children: animal })

        .sum(function (d) {
            console.log(+d.First);
            return +d.First;
        })
      ;

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack(root).leaves())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.package); });

    node.append("title")
        .text(d3.csv("animalcount.csv", function (d) {
            d.First = +d.First;

            console.log(+d.First);
            return d.Animal + "\n" + format(+d.Frist);
        }));

    node.append("text")
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .data(function (d) { return d.Animal + "\n" + format(+d.First); })
        .enter().append("tspan")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("font-size","11px")
        .style("z-index", "500")
        .text(function (d) { return d; });
});

</script>
```

The CSV file data:

```
Animal  First   Second  Third   Fourth  Fifth   Sixth   Seventh Eighth  Nineth  Tenth
Dog 17  7   6   5   4   3   2   2   1   1
Cat 5   4   3   2   1   1   1   1   1   1
Unicorn 3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2   2   2
Guinea-pig  5   3   2   2   1   1               
Seagull 16  11  9   6   6   4   4   3   3   2
Albatross   5   5   5   5   5   5   3   3   3   3
Deer    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Elk 3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
Salmon  8   7   7   7   7   6   5   4   4   4
Shark   16  16  15  14  12  10  8   3   3   3
```

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Lookup the properties of a CSV file and then see if your file fits these properties. Use the Developer Tools to see the content of the variable `animal`

Comment: I made the CSV file by saving as a CSV from Excel so I don't know what I could have done to make it not fit the properties of a CSV file. As I mentioned it also already does take data from the file to create the circles, so it can't be a problem with the file formatting or nothing would work at all. When using Developer Tools to check the variables, d returns all the data in the file, while d.Animal returns unidentified and +d.First returns NaN, but only when trying to append title and text.

Comment: what is `d.columns` look like? If Excel has saved the file you show there is something terribly wrong with Excel. What does the acronym CSV mean?

Comment: Oh the file probably doesn't look exactly like that I just copy/pasted the data from the file so people could see what was in it. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. d.columns outputs Animal, First, Second, Third etc.

Comment: Is `d.columns` an Array with 11 entries? Where are the **commas** in the file you show?

Comment: Yep. The commas would be between every entry on each row, so Animal, First, Second, etc and next row Dog, 17, 7, 6 etc. but they are added by excel when saved in the file so when I open the excel file they're separated in cells, hence why copying and pasting doesn't show them here

Comment: Your file looks more like a TSV Tab Separated, Excel detects if it finds commas or tabs and uses that if you don't specify.

Comment: That's because, as I said, I copied this directly from inside Excel, where the commas aren't written out. Inside Excel everything is inside different cells, but I saved it as a CSV file. If there was an issue with file format I wouldn't be getting anything at all, but it does already render the circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you show file content don't copy it from the application using that file but use a plain text editor to copy from.

I have added commas to your file and adjusted the code.

There is absolutely no need to read the csv again. All data is already there. Use the Developer Tools to inspect the data provided in the lambda functions. No need to keep using `+d.First`, and `d.Frist` does not exist.

Also have a close look at the use of `tspan` in the bl.ocks example and in your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<svg width="1200" height="500" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="10" text-anchor="middle"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var format = d3.format(",d");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);

var pack = d3.pack()
    .size([width, height])
    .padding(10);

d3.csv("animalcount.csv", function(d) {
    d.First = +d.First;
    return d;
}, function(error, animal) {
  if (error) throw error;

    var root = d3.hierarchy({ children: animal })
        .sum(function (d) {return d.First;})
      ;

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack(root).leaves())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.package); });

    node.append("title")
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.Animal + "\n" + format(d.data.First); });

    node.append("text")
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .data(function (d) { return d.data.Animal + "\n" + format(d.data.First); })
        .enter().append("tspan")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("font-size","11px")
        .style("z-index", "500")
        .text(function (d) { return d; });
});

</script>
```